# Mongoose bulk update/save

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I read that `Model.collection.insert` is faster than `Model.create`.

I have 1kk users in `User.collection`, I want to update them all every 1 minute:
This is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./models/user');
const async = require('async');

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

User.find({}, (err, docs) => {
    async.mapSeries(docs, (doc, callback) => {
        doc.value = getRandomArbitrary(0,100);
        doc.save((err) => {
            callback(err, doc);
        });
    }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) return err;
        console.log('completed');
    });
});
```

Is it a good way to accomplish this? It takes mode than 1 minute, How do I can increase performance?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it now is to wait for one thing being saved before going to the other one. You can parallelize it (completely or partially) to make it finish faster.

You can use `async.map` instead of `async.mapSeries` to make it work in parallel.

Or you can use `async.mapLimit` to limit the number of operations taking place at the same time.

See:

- https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map
- https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapLimit
- https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapSeries

Example with `async.map`:

```
User.find({}, (err, docs) => {
    async.map(docs, (doc, callback) => {
        doc.value = getRandomArbitrary(0,100);
        doc.save((err) => {
            callback(err, doc);
        });
    }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) return err;
        console.log('completed');
    });
});
```

Example with `async.mapLimit`:

```
const LIMIT = 10;
User.find({}, (err, docs) => {
    async.mapLimit(docs, LIMIT, (doc, callback) => {
        doc.value = getRandomArbitrary(0,100);
        doc.save((err) => {
            callback(err, doc);
        });
    }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) return err;
        console.log('completed');
    });
});
```

Just the `LIMIT` to whatever number you want.

Comment: async.map is dangerous operation, it block event-loop (unless you spawn separate child-process) and it cause memory leak. Thanks, async.mapLimit is the best option